# Using openCV to read an image from Amazon S3

Tags: c++, web-services, image-processing, opencv, amazon-s3

I am aware that there are multiple C++ libraries to access data from Amazon S3, using cURL. Using them I can download an image to the local machine, read it into OpenCV, and delete the original file.

But, I was wondering if it would be possible to read an image directly from S3 into OpenCV directly as say, a Mat object.

Would anyone be able to help me accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [cv::imdecode](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#cv-imdecode), which will load a buffer with some image data (png, jpeg, etc.) from memory into a matrix.

```
// Suppose that a std::vector<char> contains the data loaded by Curl.
std::vector<char> data;
// The template<typename T> explicit cv::Mat::Mat(const std::vector<T>& vec)
// constructor gives this vector a cv::Mat header.
cv::Mat data_mat(data);
// Now use cv::imdecode to decode the image to a BGR matrix.
cv::Mat image(cv::imdecode(data_mat));
```

Comment: I am currently reading the image into an input stream (using the [Poco](http://www.pocoproject.org) library) and trying to load it into a Mat file, but am not very successful.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with Poco, however, if you can download the image as a file, it must be somewhere stored in the memory first, and then written to the disk. What you should do is reading those bytes to a large enough buffer in memory, then call `cv::imdecode`.

Comment: Poco gets the HTTP response from the given URI. I am able to read it into an istream.

This is how the data is obtained into istream: `std::istream& rs = session.receiveResponse(response);`

And then, I convert it into a vector<char> using:
`std::vector<char> raw_data((std::istream_iterator<char> rs)),std::istream_iterator<char>());`

After this, I am using `cv::imdecode` for the rest: `cv::Mat image_data(raw_data);
  cv::Mat image(cv::imdecode(image_data,1));`
It compiles fine, but when I run it, I am getting an error that says, `unsupported or unrecognized array type in cvGetMat`.

Comment: I noticed that I am getting the error only when I try to `cv::imshow` the image.

Comment: This happens because `cv::imdecode` does not signal errors, but returns an empty matrix in case of failure. You should try to check the response body: is that really an image file (look at the first few bytes), or is that something else (some HTTP headers, a 40x response).

Comment: Another problem might be that the `std::istream` returned by Poco might be skipping whitespace, you can try `sr >> std::noskipws` as `skipws` is set for streams by default which may or may not make sense for a HTTP response.

Comment: I tried what you said and it worked! I had to change the way I read the image using the Poco library, though.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is what I had to do, as far as the Poco side of it goes.

`std::auto_ptr<std::istream> pStr(URIStreamOpener::defaultOpener().open(uri));`
`StreamCopier::copyToString(*pStr.get(), str);`

This would get the image from the supplied URI into the string `str` without any intermediate storage. The rest is as Kristoff explained.